# Reading CFA of a DNG image in matlab generates all-zero image

Tags: matlab, dng

I wrote the matlab code as https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/ mentioned to read the Color Filter Array of my DNG file, the code is as below:

```
Info=imfinfo('xxx.dng');
tiffHandle=Tiff(('xxx.dng'),'r');
offsets=TiffHandle.getTag('SubIFD');
setSubDirectory(TiffHandle,offsets(1));
CFA=double(read(TiffHandle));
```

The resultant CFA is an all-zero matrix that plotted as an pure black image. I wonder how to solve this problem and read the bayer array of the DNG image? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to upload your `.dng` file somewhere if you want us to take a look.. Otherwise, your issue is "unreproducible" and might lead to the closure of the question (unless of course there's a very strict format to these files, any demo file will do, and you are just looking for general code to read `.dng` files).

Comment: DNG is Digital Negative image format, which is a kind of RAW image developed by Adobe, and sorry for don't know how to upload my DNG image file onto Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current answer to this question is you should change the backward version of your DNG image to 1.3 instead of 1.4 and turn on "Uncompressed" option in Adobe DNG Converter, or use `-dng1.3 -u` in command line, then the cfa array can be normally read.